# Linux kernel hashtable struct hlist_head

Tags: linux-kernel, hashtable

Can anybody tell me the location where kernel hashtable struct hlist_head and struct hlist_node is defined in the linux kernel? I searched in free-electrons.com but couldn't get hold of the defination.

Comment: [Simply searched](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=hlist_head) by the type's name: `hlist_head`. It will be the [second link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L189) among 3 of `Defined as a struct type in:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in types.h

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h#L189

It's also in a few other places. Check Linux Cross Reference.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=hlist_head